# Why are bar chart x-axis ticks showing strange and wrong negative values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

Why is my X-axis ticks showing Negative values when the Xaxis values range from 43990 - 44003.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[44000, 44001, 44002, 44003, 43990, 43991, 43992, 43993, 43994, 43995, 43996, 43997, 43998, 43999]
y=[8, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 10, 4, 11, 4, 10, 17, 19]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I am seeing the following output. I was expecting x-axis to range from 43990 - 44003
[image: why negative x-axis ticks ?]

I have tried this on a couple of machines, all showing similar strange behaviour on recent versions of python and matplotlib (tried a few different versions)

> Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
>   [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
>
> Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31)

Strangely enough many trivial toy example x and y arrays are giving me expected figures.

For e.g the follwowing snippet shows the expected graph with correct x-axis tick labels

```
x=[20,30,90,70, 50, 60, 80, 70]
y=[3,2,5,10, 3, 9, 7, 6]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: correct result for above example]

What obvious thing am i missing here ?

Comment: do you want to preserve the order of the x values?

Comment: The other question answers the same thing, but it didn't turn up in my extensive search for an anwer. I believe the way this question is framed provides few value additions - 1 very simple/basic example , (2) calling out -ve values which really confused , which might help others to find out the answer. Would providing a link to the other question address your concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the offset:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Another option would be to input custom tick labels:

```
plt.bar(x, y, tick_label=x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... it works.  If I was using axes to plot (i.e like ax.bar(x,y)) do you know the equalent of your first solution ?

Comment: @jithu83 Yeah, its the same: `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "+4.4e4" in the bottom right-hand corner of your figure. For example the tick label "-4" should be read as: 44000 - 4 = 43996

Comment: Assumng "+4.4e4" means 44000, what does -2, -4 ...etc indicate ? (44000 - 4 ) ?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Your graph has +4.4e4 at the bottom. If that is true then it appears to be correct. 4.4e4 +4 = 44004 and 44000 - 10 = 43990. So I confused by your question since plot scale seems correct.